# How to make sure S3 doesn't put parallel event to lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My architecture allows files to be put in s3 for which Lambda function runs concurrently. However, the files being put in S3 are somehow overwriting because of some other process in a gap of milliseconds. Those multiple put events for the same file are causing the lambda to trigger multiple times for the same event.

Is there a threshold I can set on s3 events (something that doesn't trigger the lambda multiple times for the same file event.)

Or what kind of s3 event only occurs when a file is created and not updated?

There is already a code in place which checks if the trigger file is present. if not, it creates the trigger file. But that is also of no use since the other process is very fast to put files is s3.

Something like this below -

```
    try:
        s3_client.head_object(Bucket=trigger_bucket, Key=trigger_file)
    except ClientError as _:
        create_trigger_file(
            s3_client, trigger_bucket, trigger_file
        )
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to configure S3 events to only trigger once, or only when an object is created and not updated. Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? That is, why do you call it a "trigger file" and what are you actually wanting to accomplish (as opposed to _how_)?

Comment: So the trigger files are supposed to invoke the lambda functions in parallel. The s3 events sends the key path to the file. Since these are generating multiple events. The lambda is invoking and processing for the same file in two different invocations. Thats a waste of compute time and power.

Comment: Yes, but what is the bigger picture -- Why are you creating these "trigger files" -- is the Lambda function processing their contents? Why are they being overwritten so often? What is the end goal you are trying to achieve, rather than _how?_

Comment: The trigger files are being created to merge pdfs from different locations. These trigger files contains locations of those files. So when i download these files in efs, and try to merge the errors occur due to file locks. If there is a way to limit the overwriting, then there wont be multiple invocations. The reason why they are being written is due to multiple lambdas working in parallel to write the file.

Comment: If processing speed and volume is not an issue then maybe consider changing you design for S3 to trigger a Lambda that will first put the file details in a FIFO SQS Queue configured with de-duplication. Then attach your current processing Lambda to the SQS queue (you will need to change payload to cater for a SQS event instead of S3 event).

Comment: @TobievanderMerwe How do I configure the SQS queue with deduplication? Is that possible?

Comment: To configure FIFO SQS with deduplication: FIFO SQS->Create queue->Configuration->Content-based deduplication. Any message entering the queue will be hashed using the body of the message and any message enetering within 5 min with the same has value will be considered a duplicate and removed.

Answer (score 2):

You could configure Amazon S3 to send events to an Amazon SQS FIFO (first-in-first-out) queue. The queue could then [trigger the Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/).

The benefit of using a FIFO queue is that each message has a [Message Group ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html). A FIFO queue will only provide one message to the AWS Lambda function per Message Group ID. It will not send another message with the same Message Group ID until the earlier one has been fully processed. If you set the Message Group Id to be the `Key` of the S3 object, then it would effectively have a separate queue for each object created in S3.

This method would allow Lambda functions to run in parallel for different objects, but for each particular Key there would only be a maximum of one Lambda function executing.

Comment: The problem with this is.. since in my arch the lambdas are running in parallel and they are overwriting the trigger files in parallel and multiple times, replacing this with SQS can also create multiple queue items in SQS. (I still don't know how sqs works)

Can SQS be configured like a set? with unique keys in and it wont allow another key of same value to get inserted?

Comment: The method I have suggested above will prohibit certain 'sets' of messages from triggering parallel executions of Lambda. However, they will all trigger Lambda eventually. You will need to code your own logic in Lambda if you want to stop the function if the data has been previously processed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your problem is that multiple invocations of the AWS Lambda function are attempting to access the same files at the same time.

To avoid this, you could modify the settings on the Lambda function to [Manage Lambda reserved concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) by **setting the reserved concurrency to 1**. This will only allow a single invocation of the Lambda function to run at any time.

[image: AWS Lambda reserved concurrency]

Comment: Cant do that as the solution needs other trigger files to be processed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your architecture needs to write to the same file. This is not scalable. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel):

> Amazon S3 does not support object locking for concurrent writers. If two PUT requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the latest timestamp wins. If this is an issue, you must build an object-locking mechanism into your application.

So, think about your architecture. Why do you have a process that wants to process multiple times to the same file at the same time? The lambda's that create these S3 files, do they need to write to the same file? If I understand your use case correctly, every lambda could create an unique file. For example, based on the name of the PDF you want to create or with some timestamp added to it. That ensures you don't have write collisions. You could create lifecycle rules on the S3 bucket to delete the files after a day or so, such that you don't increase your storage costs too much. Or have a lambda delete the file when it is finished with it.

Comment: The trigger files are different form the pdf files. each files gets uploaded as pdf and writes as pdf single time only. Its the trigger files that is being overwritten. the object locking thing is good. but how do i achieve it with s3